# django.template.exceptions.TemplateDoesNotExist: Error

Tags: django

I'm learning to use Django for some side projects but I keep getting the same error whenever I try to set a template. I've tried giving the directory for the app, and when I check the error it says that the file does not exist. When I go and look at the directory it does exist though?

[The Error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NeNgd.png)

[My Directory](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZVFjn.png)

Comment: Try: `playground/templates/playground/hello.html`.

Comment: We need more information, how are you calling the template? Are you using a view from views.py or directly from url.py?? We need more information. It seems you are not calling the template correctly.